# How to check duplicate from a hierarchial point via stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

```sql
create table Label (IdLabel int, IdParentLabel int , Name varchar(30))

Insert Into Label Values ( 1, null, 'root')
Insert Into Label Values ( 2, 1, 'child1')
Insert Into Label Values ( 3, 1, 'child2')
Insert Into Label Values ( 4, 2, 'grandchild1')
Insert Into Label Values ( 5, 3, 'grandchild2')
```

**Condition:** no label can have any two children in its hierarchy with the same name. E.g. 'grandchild1' can't have a label 'child1' ; but 'grandchild2' can have a label 'child1'

I wrote this stored procedure which fails the above scenario:

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CheckLabelExistsInHierarchy]
    @LabelName nvarchar(50),
    @IdParentLabel int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    
    WITH HierarchyCTE AS 
    (
        SELECT 
            IdLabel, IdParentLabel, Name
        FROM 
            Label
        WHERE 
            IdParentLabel = @IdParentLabel
    
        UNION ALL
    
        SELECT 
            l.IdLabel, l.IdParentLabel, l.Name
        FROM 
            Label l
        INNER JOIN 
            HierarchyCTE h ON l.IdLabel = h.IdParentLabel
    )
    SELECT 
        CAST(CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS bit) AS Result
    FROM 
        HierarchyCTE
    WHERE 
        Name = @LabelName
END
```

**Expected result:** is 1 for above condition

Comment: Please show the results you are expecting.

Comment: I don't know, for me it works? exec CheckLabelExistsInHierarchy 'child1', 3 -- fails
exec CheckLabelExistsInHierarchy 'child1', 2 -- OK

Answer (score 0):

I think that your procedure did not check if names are in same branches. This seems to work:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CheckLabelExistsInHierarchy]
        @LabelName nvarchar(50)
  AS
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
    
        WITH HierarchyCTE AS (
            SELECT IdLabel, IdParentLabel, Name, 0 duplicates
            FROM Label
            WHERE name = @labelname
    
            UNION ALL
    
            SELECT l.IdLabel, l.IdParentLabel, l.Name, 
                   duplicates + case when l.Name = @labelName then 1 else 0 end
            FROM Label l
            INNER JOIN HierarchyCTE h ON l.IdLabel = h.IdParentLabel
        )
        SELECT CAST(CASE WHEN max(duplicates) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS bit) AS Result
        FROM HierarchyCTE
    END
```

[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/k2hgRBqm)

I changed starting point of hierarchy to searched name, removed parameter `@IdParentLabel` which seems redundant (but you can add it again if you want to start only from certain point). Then I added duplicates counter and made basic tests in dbfiddle.

Comment: Thanks, but  a label name in one branch might not be duplicate but in another branch it might be duplicate. For my above condition in post, if IdParentLabel = 4 and Label = 'Child1' it will be considered as duplicate because there is already a 'Child1' in the hierarchy, but id IdParenLabel = 5 , then it will not be a duplicate

Comment: It works as you said: [situation1](https://dbfiddle.uk/P53P9E54) and [situation2](https://dbfiddle.uk/uOiENxPF).

Comment: that works, but my requirement is to start from a certain point, so it will check the IdParentLabel and then it will traverse up and down and check for a duplicate

Comment: This requires a small change: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/h2JspYlN) in procedure.

Comment: Insert Into Label Values ( 10, 4, 'child1') --> At this point it should not work, I am trying to impose a logic so that this insert will be invalid after the sp return this condition will create a duplicate scenario. Your sp works fine except this scenario. root--> child1 --> grandchild1 --> child1 will be considered duplicate because it has same label name in hierarchy